# Earliest Telepathic bonding story?

Tags: history-of, telepathy

I was wondering about the earliest use of telepathic bonding in both fantasy as well as science fiction. I guess I should narrow it down by excluding simple telepathic 'speaking'. So, I define it as two characters sharing both mental 'voice' and mental 'emotion' telepathically in the context of a friendship. I'd separate out human-human, human-animal(otherwise 'normal'), human-animal(having essentially human level intelligence), and human-alien intelligence.
Someone mentioned E. Hamilton's 1948 story The Valley of Creation, but I am unfamiliar with that - although I do know it involves intelligent telepathic animals. A. Norton's 1952 StarMan's Son fits the 'normal animal' bonding, iirc. Anything earlier? And how about the other 3 types? In sci-fi? In fantasy?

Comment: This is a very broad question I'll have to think on before coming up with a full answer. That said, the first of Lewis Padgett's telepathic stories, "The Piper's Son", was published in 1945, and deals with people who have mutated to evolve telepathy, and is very much oriented around the bonds created by it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was the first telepath?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126687/who-was-the-first-telepath)

Comment: What is the difference between "simple telepathic 'speaking" and "telepathic 'bonding'"?