# Why does Harry address the Weasley-parents with "Mr. & Mrs"?

Tags: harry-potter

The relationship between Harry & the Weasley-parents grows to be quite close. At one point I think Molly even says that Harry is like a son to her. Nevertheless Harry keeps addressing them with "Mr. Weasley" and "Mrs. Weasley" and doesn't use their first names.

Why does he do that? Is it a normal thing to do in Britain?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, please move any further talk to [chat].

Comment: Don't forget that asking whether it is a normal thing in Britain *now* is the wrong question to ask - the books were set starting 25 years ago!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The short answer is that it's perfectly normal in the UK for a child to address
the parents of a school friend as Mister and Mrs, [even into adulthood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197712/whats-the-relationship-between-persons-using-non-symetrically-first-name-and-mr/197715). The flipside is that it would seem very odd if he started referring to them by their first names even if you had a scene where they told him to do so.

You might also want to note that it would make picking up a subsequent book harder for new readers since you'd basically have changed their character names.

Comment: For the record, every instance of "call me Molly" I've found on google leads to a Molly/Harry sexual encounter slashfic.

Comment: the only instance of "call me *X*" where Rule 34 isn't necessarily invoked, might be "call me Ishmael".

Comment: @SQB You are aware that that Moby *Dick* is a *sperm* whale?

Comment: @SQB - You may be unaware that in the original book, the line read "*Call me Ishmael, **you sexy beast**". The publisher felt that the tone was over-familiar.

Comment: Further to that, note that in some parts of the independent schools system it is perfectly normal for the children to address _one another_ by surname only.  Draco Malfoy's "Potter", "Weasley", and "Granger" are in fact how _all_ pupils address one another in such schools.  Adults would be "sir" or "miss", or "Mr Weasley" or "Mrs Weasley".

Comment: @JdeBP you may want to add that as an independent answer; if even pupils address each other by their surnames, surely they wouldn't address each other's parents by their first names.

Comment: This isn't confined to Angosphere. You call friends' parents by their patronymics as a sign of respect pretty much all your life as well in Russia.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not sure whether to cry foul for TMI or be glad you saved a lot of people from Googling the phrase.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida I assume you meant by first name and patronymic. Just patronymic works only between close friends.

Comment: On the flip-side, Harry does start calling Professor Lupin "Remus" in the middle of Deathly Hallows. It's rather jarring, imo.

Comment: Before the late 1970s, it was the norm in the US, too (at least in the South).

Comment: Up here in Ohio it's *still* quite normal for kids (my kids and their friends, in particular) to address the parents of friends as "Mr. and Mrs. Abc". It'd feel very awkward if one of my kids friends referred to me as "Bob" - but I doubt they know what my first name is, so it hasn't been an issue. Growing up parents of friends were *always* "Mr. Abc" or "Mrs. Xyz". Teachers were always "Sir", "Ma'am", or "Mr"/"Mrs"/"Miss" with last name appended. ALWAYS.

Comment: @JdeBP - I can vouch that last-name addressing amongst students is common in private "prep" schools in the USA too. Or at least it was way back in the '80's when I went to one.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure that this needs to be a competing answer, but since other people have pressed for it:

Yes, it is perfectly normal in some parts of British society.  There are some parts of the independent schools system where this form of address between children and adults is perfectly normal, and indeed the children address *one another* by surname only.

Draco Malfoy's "Potter", "Weasley", and "Granger" are in fact how all pupils address one another in such schools.  Adults, both masters/mistresses and the parents of other pupils, would be "sir" or "miss", or "Mr Weasley" or "Mrs Weasley".

Whether Hogwarts is an independent school, or is state-funded, is a good question (especially as many people's assumption that it is independent seems flatly contradicted by recent pronouncements from the author).  But it's *another* question.  ☺  To this question: Yes, what you see is quite normal, and one of the many facets of this particular British schools sector that one can see reflected in the stories.

Don't mistake this for thinking that this is necessarily common across British society as a whole.  It is not at all unified in this respect.  There are, equally, parts of the British schools system to which these mores seem utterly alien and even appalling.  So it can be surprising even to other Brits to hear anecdotes such as:

- One can go through school without *ever* learning the first names of some of one's fellow pupils.  As someone who systematically attempted to learn people's first names, I can report from direct experience that it even went so far as there being people who actually refused to tell me their first names.
- Faced with two pupils sharing the same surname, rather than resort to given names as disambiguators, my Lower Fourth form-master promptly gave both pupils ad-hoc nicknames based upon their (then) appearance, which pretty much stuck with them for the rest of their school lives.

There is also a movement amongst teachers that objects to female teachers being "miss" whilst male teachers are "sir".  The twain are not equivalent in status.  This is part of a larger linguistic debate over the titles for men and for women, of course.  ([I rather like James Tiptree Jr's gender-neutral approach to the subject.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85713/21871))

Equally, do not mistake this for being something that is strictly peculiar to independent schools.  It is just far more common and far more pronounced, to the inclusion of pupils, there.  There are some state-funded schools which adopt similar codes to lesser or greater extent.  To give two current examples:

- Addressing adults in this manner is actually in rule #1 of the School Rules for the Queen's School, a state-funded school in Hertfordshire, today:

  > Be polite, kind and helpful to teachers, support staff, visitors and other students, regardless of their age, colour, religion, race, language, sexuality or background.  Address male staff as “Sir” or “Mr” with their surname and female staff as Ma’am’, “Mrs” or “Miss” with their surname.
- It is in the first rule of the School Rules for St Dunstan's School, an Academy Converter in Somerset, today:

  > Behave **politely and sensibly** at all times. Show respect for other people and their property.  Female staff should be addressed as Mrs, Miss with the surname. Male staff as ‘Sir’ or Mr with the surname.

Yes, being required to address teachers in this way does bleed over into addressing *all* adults, in and out of school, in this way.  In the opinions of some, *it is intended to*.

If you want to read even further about this across society as a whole, then you can do worse than to start with the publications of the Society for Name Studies in Britain (president: Peter McClure, Honorary Professor within the Institute for Name-Studies, University of Nottingham).

## Further reading

- *[School Rules](http://queens.herts.sch.uk/school-rules/)*.  The Queen's School.  2016.
- "School Rules".  *[Code of Behaviour](http://st-dunstans.somerset.sch.uk/parents/general-information/code-of-behaviour/)*.  St Dunstan's School.  2016.
- Tim Walker (2014-10-06).  *[A tale of two schools](http://independent.co.uk/news/education/education-news/a-tale-of-two-schools-542821.html)*.  The Independent.
- Maev Kennedy (2014-05-13).  *[Just who is that woman at the front of the class?](https://theguardian.com/education/2014/may/13/debate-over-female-teachers-called-sir-or-miss)*.  The Guardian.
- Robyn Wilder (2014-02-19). *[23 Things That Happen To You At A British Boarding School](https://www.buzzfeed.com/robynwilder/23-things-that-happen-to-you-at-a-british-boarding-school)*.  buzzfeed.
- Pete Wharmby (2013-02-13).  *[Ofsted Report: Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry](http://petewharmby.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/ofsted-report-hogwarts-school-of.html)*.  Life, teaching and other distractions.  blogspot.
- Peter McClure (1981).  "[Nicknames and petnames: linguistic forms and social contexts](http://snsbi.org.uk/Nomina_pdf/Nomina_v5_p63_McClure.pdf)".  *Nomina*.  ISSN 0141 6340.  vol. **4**.  pp. 63–76.  Society for Name Studies in Britain and Ireland.

Comment: Given that neither Molly, nor Arthur were Harry's teachers, nor his peers at school, I'm not sure how this relates to the question asked.

Comment: @Valorum gives background information that enables the reader to understand the issue better.

Comment: @SáT - Hmm. It's tangential at best. I've not downvoted, but nor have I upvoted. I do feel that this should have stayed a comment.

Comment: "many people's assumption that [Hogwarts] is independent seems flatly contradicted by recent pronouncements from the author" -- the source of finance isn't really strictly relevant here.  The distinction you're drawing between an independent and a state school is more a matter of *culture* than anything else, and Hogwarts' culture is certainly closer to a typical independent school than a state school ...

Comment: ...  its selectivity in pupils who are admitted (i.e. only those with magical capability), the fact that it is a boarding school, that its staff are largely drawn from its former pupils, and its use of the "house" system are all common features of independent schools but somewhat rarer in British state schools (although I believe the house system is becoming somewhat more common in state schools these days, probably as a reaction to the popularity of the HP books).

Comment: I'll write it _again_ with boldface:  **That's _another_ question.**  (I was surprised that this WWW site does not already have it.)  Comments to an answer to a different question are not for squeezing _your own answer_ to it into.  If you want to answer the question of whether Hogwarts is an independent or a state school, then you know where the "Ask question" hyperlink and the "post an answer to your own question" checkbox are.  I was pressed into writing this answer.  Consider yourself pressed into writing an outright question.  (-: