# What is the shortest distance between Pyke and Qarth assuming that the world is round in the Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Is it possible to attack Westeros from Qarth, if one sail to the East? How far is it in the book?

Here's an infographic map:
[image: http://static2.techinsider.io/image/5624f97e9dd7cc19008c2d52-1200-992/ti_graphics_got-maps_full-map.png]

Comment: This map is rather bad in this context - there's lots of land in Essos further East than Qarth.

Comment: See newer map http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/File:Ice_and_Fire_World_Map.png

Answer (score 7):

It's unknown.

[Martin said:](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1122/)

> No one has ever crossed the Sunset Sea to learn what lies on the other side

Comment: Map I linked suggests it would be much further if one tried to go west.

Answer (score 4):

Based on JRRM's [own pronouncements](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1206/) about the [size of the world of Westeros](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22702/what-is-the-shape-of-the-world-of-westeros-and-do-the-westerosi-know/50041#50041), and assuming that the lands of Essos and Westeros are roughly the width of Europe and Central Asia (around 3000 miles), then the distance between Qarth and Pyke could be anything upwards of **75,000 miles of open ocean**.

> "**Interviewer :** *Is your world round? I mean if Dany traveled far
>   enough east couldnt she come to the other side of westeros?*
>
> **GRRM :** *Yes, the world is round. Might be a little larger than ours, though. I was thinking more like Vance's Big Planet.... but
>   don't hold me to that*."

That would certainly explain why, when asked, he was categorical that [no-one has ever managed to circumnavigate the world.](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1122/)

[image]

To the same scale as your map above, the planet would look something like this, assuming that the northern reaches of Westeros extend up into the poles.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, Martin says little bigger, only compares to Big Planet, not says that it would be that big.

Comment: @Mithoron  - At the present time, this is all that we have to go on. If you can come up with a better quote or something that clarifies his statement, I'll be delighted to add it to my answer on the other question,

Comment: Thank you, this world is pretty huge! Maybe Danny should discover new continents instead of conquering Westeros.

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar - I rather suspect that future maps and future statements will shrink this world to a more manageable size. Until then, this answer stands.